# Am I asking good questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I have the impression that my questions are not getting answers, and I'm not sure why. Since, I'm learning by myself, I may be oblivious to what's interesting in some area, and ask some uninteresting questions.

Is this the case? Is there a way I can improve myself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: In my last 10 questions, 3 got answered, and one of those was by me... =D

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, several of your unanswered questions seem to be of the format:

> I read this in a book, is it true?

One problem with that is that it's a snippet with no context, and no one's going to be inclined to dig out the original text, go through all the context, give an interpretation of the snippet, and then look for evidence for and against it. So it seems to me - and this is just my opinion - that there's just not enough substance in the question to make it answerable, really.

Other times, it appears to be based on a false premise (e.g. that monetary policy has no redistributive effect).

Comment: In the first paragraph, you're suggesting to give more context? Why do you say that it's a false premise? I may try to look for the reference if you want...